# Drupal: How can one hook exit in a custom module be called in every page request?

Tags: drupal

How can one hook exit in a custom module be called in every page request of a drupal website?

Here is the hook exit code in a custom module:

```
<?php
function cec_monitoring_exit() {
    if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
        // database inserts here
    }
}
?>
```

Is it because of the if condition or someting else? Because some of the custom modules are calling the hook 'cec_monitoring_exit()' but some other custom modules don't.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: The condition will only match node pages, but the hook should be called on every page request

Comment: @jeremy: I see so it must be called in every page request but it is not called in some of the custom modules. What I am trying to do is identify a logged in user's unique page view for the current month.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of when this hook doesn't fire? I am not sure what you mean about it not being called in some custom modules.

Comment: @Andrew: When visit a custom module I created it is not being called. But in some custom module, the hook exit is being called.

Comment: By 'visit a custom module', do you mean 'visit a page *created by* a custom module'?

Comment: @henrick: I mean 'visit a page of a custom module'

Comment: @marknt15: I edited my answer below accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by `it is not called in some of the custom modules` either, so just speculating here that you might mean custom pages provided by other modules:

As Jeremy and Googletorp stated already, your if block

```
if ((arg(0) == 'node') && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == '') {
    // database inserts here
}
```

will only evaluate to true if the user is requesting a full node page (e.g. 'node/42'). It will **not match any other page** like a term view (e.g. 'taxonomy/term/36') or the default frontpage ('node') or a view page provided by the views module (might/have/any/path), etc..

So your database inserts would only take place for node pages, and nothing else.

If you want to log *every* page request, you can just remove the if block and do your database insertions directly.

---

**Edit after clarification in comments** (`cec_monitoring_exit()` does not get invoked for some pages created by other modules):

I can only see two possible reasons for this.

The first reason would be an error occurring right after the page output, but before the invocation of your `hook_exit()` implementation (*check your server logs for php errors on requests for the failing pages*). If you take a look at 'index.php' (top level folder of your Drupal instance):

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
      drupal_site_offline();
      break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
  print theme('page', $return);
}

drupal_page_footer();
```

you can see that the page output is generated by printing the result of `theme('page', $return)`. The invocation of `hook_exit()` happens right after that in [`drupal_page_footer()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_page_footer/6).

So you should check (preferably via debugger, but you could also use print statements) if `drupal_page_footer()` gets executed on the pages in question at all. If it gets called, the error might occur in a `hook_exit()` implementation of another module that gets called before yours, so you'd need to check those.

The second reason would be if one of the modules would circumvent the standard Drupal execution flow by calling theme('page', ...) itself and stopped the execution afterwards. In this case, `drupal_page_footer()` would not be called, because the execution would have stopped long before during the call to `menu_execute_active_handler()`. Note that no established Drupal Module would do this, so it is pretty unlikely.

Besides these options, I have no further idea on what could cause this.

Comment: Hi Henrick, thanks for the reply. Even if I replaced the whole code inside of the cec_monitoring_exit() hook with die('<hr />died here');the die function will not run in some custom modules.

The one hook function I created must be called in every drupal page request right? But in some custom modules, the hook exit is not called. I'm wondering why.

Comment: @marknt15: You need to explain what you mean by 'not run *in* some custom modules'! Why *in*? Do you place the same function in several different modules?

Comment: @henrick: I only have one hook function in one custom module and I did not have any other hook exit function. What I mean in 'not running in some other modules' is that the hook exit is not called in some custom modules when I access a drupal page.

Comment: @henrick: Thanks for your help but I figured it out. The problem is not in drupal but in my PHP, Apache installation in Snow Leopard. I am using an individual install and it did not work. When I tried MAMP, the hook exit can now be called without doing anything in the code. Weird and I did not pinpoint exactly where is the problem in apache or php ini settings. Also, in individual install, the administer front page module is not showing up in a drupal fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are called whenever their condition is met. This is done with the use of [module_invoke_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_invoke_all/6). This means that hooks that are called on every page request, will be invoked in every page request. In your example above, your hook wont do anything in some cases, but it will still be called since Drupal wont know when it actually will do something.

This waste of resource will be limited when pages are cached, since you only will need to run the hooks when page cached page is created. Another example is whenever a node is loaded with [node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_load/6), this will result in a lot of hooks being fired, and is thus quite expensive. Thus you usually want to avoid using this whenever possible, when you want to access something on a lot of nodes like their title.

Comment: @googletorp: Thanks for your answer.In the drupal 5 manual: "This hook is run at the end of each page request." So I think in every page request, the hook cec_monitoring_exit() will always be called without condition because the hook exit has no condition requirement? Am I correct?

"In your example above, your hook wont do anything in some cases, but it will still be called since Drupal wont know when it actually will do something." - so it will still be called but why in some of the custom modules it is not being called?

Comment: It's worth noting that unless you reset node_load, it holds a copy of each node in memory. Repeated loading of a node already in memory is not expensive. (So a node_load to access information about the current node page in hook_exit is fine.)

Answer (score 0):

@marknt15 what i think your failing to realize here is its all based on name so that hook being the hook_exit() in your case AKA _exit() is called when it is placed with a prefix of the calling modules name eg cec_monitoring_exit() will only work in the cec_monitoring module but in you other custom module named say  marknt15_loves_drupal then it would meed to use hook_exit() like  marknt15_loves_drupal_exit()

drupal then calls it and all other hooks with ...
call_user_func_array('modulename'_'hookname') or something very similar